# Can I use 2x turn speed on a New 3DS?

Tags: code-name-steam

In *Code Name: S.T.E.A.M.*, there is an option to fast forward enemy turns by 2x on a standard 3DS or 3x on a New 3DS.

Is there a way to use 2x turn speed on a New 3DS? Or am I stuck with 3x speed?